# Visualforce component field value bind issue

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, visualforce-component, controller-extension

I have following class

```
/**
 * extension class for handling VF page actions
 */
global with sharing class SQX_Extension_Random_object extends SQX_Controller_Sign_Off {

    private SQX_Random_object__c mainRecord            = null; // random_object record in which action is to be preformed
    private ApexPages.StandardController controller = null; // controller of the extension

    /**
     * constructor method of the class to check esig status and assign main record and controller
     */
    public SQX_Extension_Random_object(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        this.controller = controller;
        mainRecord = (SQX_Random_object__c) controller.getRecord();
    }

    /**
     */
    public PageReference initiate(){
        PageReference ref = null;
        Savepoint sp = null;
        Database.SaveResult result = null;
        if(hasValidCredentials()){
            try{
                sp = Database.setSavepoint();
                mainRecord.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
                result = Database.update(mainRecord, false);

                if(result.isSuccess()){

                    ref = new ApexPages.StandardController(mainRecord).view();
                } else {
                    for(Database.Error err : result.getErrors()){
                    }
                    Database.rollback(sp);
                }

            }catch(Exception ex){
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Exception: ' + ex.getMessage()));
                if(sp != null){
                    Database.rollback(sp);
                }
            }
        } else {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, Label.TEST));
        }
        return ref;
    }

}
```

And the class has following vf page

```
<apex:page standardController="SQX_Random_object__c" extensions="SQX_Extension_Random_object" title="{!$Label.CQ_UI_Random_object_Edit} : {!SQX_Random_object__c.Name}">
    <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="{!$Label.CQ_UI_Random_object_Detail}">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!initiate}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <c:SQX_Sign_Off_Component />
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

And the component used by the vf page is

```
<apex:component access="global" controller="SQX_Controller_Sign_Off">
     <apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:outputText value="Password" />
            <apex:outputPanel >
                <apex:inputSecret value="{!SigningOffpassword}" label="Password" required="true"/>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
    </apex:pageBlockSection>

</apex:component>
```

And the controller used by the component if

```
/**
 * 
 */
global abstract class SQX_Controller_Sign_Off {

    global Boolean ES_Enabled           { get; set; } // flag to check if esig is enabled in the org
    global String SigningOffPassword    { get; set; } // password of the user signing off the action

    Id recordId;

    /**
     * 
     */
    global SQX_Controller_Sign_Off(){
        recordId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

        // get electronic signature settings
        ES__c cqES = ES__c.getInstance();
        ES_Enabled = cqES.Enabled__c;
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    global Boolean hasValidCredentials(){
        if(ES_Enabled){
            System.assert(false, esigValidation +'Username >>'+ SigningOffUsername + 'Password>> '+ SigningOffPassword);
            Boolean esigValidation = new VaidationClass().validate(SigningOffUsername, SigningOffPassword);
            return esigValidation;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

So my problem is when I enter the password in the password field in the component and click save. I am getting value as null for **SigningOffPassword** even if I enter password. For testing I have added assertion in **hasValidCredentials()** method which is called by save method **initiate()**.
I cannot bind the value.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is probably because your component has it's own copy of SQX_Controller_Sign_Off instance, where the entered values are saved. However your extension is accessing another copy of SQX_Controller_Sign_Off, which still has null values.

Comment: Any solution to fix it.

Comment: There are several ways to do this. 1. Pass attributes to your component from the page 2. Put the buttons in the component along with the field 3. There is no need to create component for such a simple forms. Put everything on the page.